# SwiftUI is there some way to get the background color of a List in light or dark mode?

Tags: swiftui

Basically the background color of a list is this gray ish color from what I see, I wanna make some row background color to match the color of the List background in both light and dark mode so I was wondering if there was maybe some built in color like secondary or primary that might be able to just get the List background color but if there isn't what color is the List background color exactly in Light mode and how I can get a row background color to be that color when the device is in light mode and to be just straight black when it's in dark mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same question. You have to set it via HEX-Value.

1. Add an extension that allows you to convert HEX to UIColor:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        assert(hex[hex.startIndex] == "#", "format expected: #rrggbb")
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 1 
        
        var rgb: UInt32 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt32(&rgb)
        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb &   0xFF00) >>  8)/255.0,
            blue:  CGFloat((rgb &     0xFF)      )/255.0,
            alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

2. Make sure you can access colorScheme environment Variable. Insert this where you also have your @State variables:

```swift
@Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
```

3. Put all your views in a VStack, so they are grouped together and add this modifiers to your new VStack:

```swift
.background(colorScheme == .light ? Color(uiColor: UIColor(hex: "#f2f2f7", alpha: 1)) : Color.black )
```

This is going to set the background to the color (#F2F2F7) if the device is set to light-mode

I hope I was able to help you!